# How to get the max value for every date in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe with UV values in a time series format from 2016-01-01 to 2020-12-31.

```
print(df.head(24))

         date      time  uv_index
0  2016-01-01  00:00:00       1.0
1  2016-01-01  01:00:00       1.0
2  2016-01-01  02:00:00       1.0
3  2016-01-01  03:00:00       1.0
4  2016-01-01  04:00:00       1.0
5  2016-01-01  05:00:00       1.0
6  2016-01-01  06:00:00       1.0
7  2016-01-01  07:00:00       1.0
8  2016-01-01  08:00:00       1.0
9  2016-01-01  09:00:00       1.0
10 2016-01-01  10:00:00       1.0
11 2016-01-01  11:00:00       1.0
12 2016-01-01  12:00:00       1.0
13 2016-01-01  13:00:00       1.0
14 2016-01-01  14:00:00       1.0
15 2016-01-01  15:00:00       1.0
16 2016-01-01  16:00:00       1.0
17 2016-01-01  17:00:00       2.0
18 2016-01-01  18:00:00       1.0
19 2016-01-01  19:00:00       1.0
20 2016-01-01  20:00:00       1.0
21 2016-01-01  21:00:00       1.0
22 2016-01-01  22:00:00       1.0
23 2016-01-01  23:00:00       1.0
```

How do I create a new column `uv_max` which takes the max `uv_index` value for each date.

```
print(df1.head(24))

         date      time  uv_index  uv_max
0  2016-01-01  00:00:00       1.0     2.0
1  2016-01-01  01:00:00       1.0     2.0
2  2016-01-01  02:00:00       1.0     2.0
3  2016-01-01  03:00:00       1.0     2.0
4  2016-01-01  04:00:00       1.0     2.0
5  2016-01-01  05:00:00       1.0     2.0
6  2016-01-01  06:00:00       1.0     2.0
7  2016-01-01  07:00:00       1.0     2.0
8  2016-01-01  08:00:00       1.0     2.0
9  2016-01-01  09:00:00       1.0     2.0
10 2016-01-01  10:00:00       1.0     2.0
11 2016-01-01  11:00:00       1.0     2.0
12 2016-01-01  12:00:00       1.0     2.0
13 2016-01-01  13:00:00       1.0     2.0
14 2016-01-01  14:00:00       1.0     2.0
15 2016-01-01  15:00:00       1.0     2.0
16 2016-01-01  16:00:00       1.0     2.0
17 2016-01-01  17:00:00       2.0     2.0
18 2016-01-01  18:00:00       1.0     2.0
19 2016-01-01  19:00:00       1.0     2.0
20 2016-01-01  20:00:00       1.0     2.0
21 2016-01-01  21:00:00       1.0     2.0
22 2016-01-01  22:00:00       1.0     2.0
23 2016-01-01  23:00:00       1.0     2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby()`+`transform()`:

```
df['uv_max']=df.groupby('date')['uv_index'].transform('max')
```